# Most elegant way to return value from within JQuery $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there a more elegant way of returning a value from the function I've pasted below : "getImageURLforPOICategory".

As you can see I've used JQuery's "each" function to iterate through an array of objects, when I find the matching value I want to return a result out of the "each" loop and then right out of the function that contains the each loop.

I've used a local variable to "cache" it and then I'm returning that. I'm not entirely sure if this is the best approach? Is there a way of returning the value directly from within the each loop?

```
Tracker.getImageURLforPOICategory = function (POICategoryID) {
 var url;
 $.each(Tracker.pointofinterestcategories, function () {
  if (this.id === POICategoryID) {
   url = this.imageurl;
   return;
  }
 }
 );
 return url;
};
```

Thanks for reading,

Cheers,

Duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't return a value from the `.each()`.

If you do a `return false;` it will stop the loop so it isn't running longer than it needs to, but you'll need to use a variable as you're doing  now.

If you don't use `$.each()`, but instead use a `for` loop, you'll be able to just:

```
return Tracker.pointofinterestcategories[ i ].imageurl
```

Comment: Great thanks for that. Reverting to a standard For loop makes sens for a such a simple operation I guess. Cheers, Duncan.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still use a for loop though.

```
Tracker.getImageURLforPOICategory = function (POICategoryID) {
    return $.grep(Tracker.pointofinterestcategories, function (item) {
        return item.id === POICategoryID;
    })[0].imageurl;
}
```

Comment: Nice.. I saw that grep function a few nights ago and was planning to explore it.. thanks for the meaty example!